# Orchard - Email validation

Tags: validation, orchardcms

Is it possible to validate if user entered an email address in correct format? (if there is anything built in it).

EDIT: Is it possible to do this in custom "Content Type"? For example when I create a form in "Orchard" for "Content Type" with "Email" field. Is there any way how to create "Content Part" in Orchard that would be self-validating?

Thank you,

Jakub

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to Orchard, but validating e-mail addresses is pretty pointless (beyond the presence of a '@' character in the middle). What you want to validate is whether the e-mail address belongs to the person using it. But you're not saying enough about your scenario.

Comment: If you are trying to do this via Orchard's built in registration process, the answer is yes, sort of. Orchard has the ability to require users to verify their email address upon registration (they have to click a verification link that they receive at the email address they register with). This is the only 100% reliable way of verifying or validating an email address.